# Creating schema in VS+SSDT without AUTHORIZATION clause

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 with SSDT 14.0.6121.0.
I created SQL Server Database Project and added a Schema object. Inside of this, I wrote

```
    CREATE SCHEMA [MySchema]
```

and created a project snapshot. However, when I deploy this DACPAC (using DacFX), I see, that the actual deploy statement is

```
    CREATE SCHEMA [MySchema] AUTHORIZATION='dbo'
```

It's always 'dbo', regardless of actual executing account, and it leads to deploy failure due to lack of permissions in some cases.

In DACPAC, code is as follows:

```
    <Element Type="SqlSchema" Name="[MySchema]">
        <Relationship Name="Authorizer">
            <Entry>
                <References ExternalSource="BuiltIns" Name="[dbo]" />
            </Entry>
        </Relationship>
    </Element>
```

Is there a way to tell SSDT, that I don't want AUTHORIZATION to be 'dbo' or any other account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - when SSDT needs to create a schema, it explicitly adds the authorization header and adds the user who owns it - if no one owns it then it puts it as dbo. There is nothing in SSDT to control this and it just does it for you.

Generally it is better to be explicit about these things and add a user who will own it, why can't you specify a user?

Comment: This package is to be run from installer, so I don't know actual user name and want it to be currently executing user. Thanks for your answer.